# Add multiple line segments in a plots between many points in R

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I'm using `geom_segment` to add line segment on a plot in R. As I have many line segments (totally 80) need to add, it seems I cannot add more lines by using "+". Is it due to the limited layers in R? Anyway, I'm wondering if there is any way to add those 80 line segments in a plot.

The following are the codes I use in my plot:

```
ggplot(df_var_g1,aes(Name,PrePost, fill=type)) + 
  geom_bar(colour="black", width=0.7, stat="identity",position=position_dodge(width=0.8)) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("#F6D3D1","#C9CFE9")) + 
  geom_segment(aes(x = 0.8, y = 0.8525, xend = 1.2, yend = 0.8665, colour = 'b'),size=1) + 
  geom_segment(aes(x = 1.8, y = 0.8525, xend = 2.2, yend = 0.8665, colour = 'c'),size=1) + 
  geom_segment(aes(x = 2.8, y = 0.8525, xend = 3.2, yend = 0.8665, colour = 'c'),size=1) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = 3.8, y = 0.8525, xend = 4.2, yend = 0.8665, colour = 'c'),size=1) + 
  geom_segment(aes(x = 4.8, y = 0.8525, xend = 5.2, yend = 0.8665, colour = 'c'),size=1) + 
  geom_segment(aes(x = 5.8, y = 0.8525, xend = 6.2, yend = 0.8665, colour = 'c'),size=1) +
  ...(perhaps 80 geom_segment here...) + 
  scale_color_manual(values=c("#FF6666","#0000FF")) + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=SDmin, ymax=SDmax), width=.1, position=position_dodge(1)) + 
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),panel.background = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"), axis.ticks.length=unit(-0.15, "cm"), axis.text.x = element_text(margin=margin(15,5,10,5,"pt")), axis.text.y = element_text(margin=margin(5,8,10,5,"pt"))) + 
  coord_cartesian(ylim=c(0.7,1.0))
```

The plot is as follows:
[image: my plot]

Can any one solve the problem? Or just get rid of `geom_segment`. I only want to add those 80 lines... Many thanks!

Comment: Can you provide your sample data by pasting the output of `dput(df_var_g1)` or a subset of `df_var_g1`, you should not need to add 80 lines. Also what determines the color of the lines -- red vs. blue?

Comment: you should be able to do this with a single geom_segment if your data are in a data.frame

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `geom_segment` - use `geom_line` with a group aesthetic.  You will need a column in your data frame that identifies which points to pair; geom_line can connect points from rows that have the same value for that column

```
ggplot(df_var_g1, aes(Name,PrePost, fill=type)) + 
    geom_bar(colour="black", width=0.7, 
        stat="identity",position=position_dodge(width=0.8)) + 
    scale_fill_manual(values=c("#F6D3D1","#C9CFE9")) + 
    # draw lines connecting points with the same value in group_column
    geom_line(aes(group_by = group_column))
```